# Can a Vue ref name contain a space

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, key, javascript-objects

Recently somebody changed an object/variable value from one without a space ("Institution") to one with a space ("Medical School").  I discovered though that this broke some code that relied
on the previous value embedded in a ref name, e.g. "newInstitution_fromDate".  Specifically the broken code was trying to refer to that variable value
-- `this.credsCaption[cred]` -- as part of the "refPrefix" preceding and including the underscore:

```
let refPrefix = `new${this.credsCaption[cred]}_`;
```

So my question is, can a Vue ref name have a space in it?  In other words, in my template can I change the ref name from "newInstitution_fromDate" to "newMedical School_fromDate"?

Answer (score 0):

The answer appears to be yes.  I changed the ref name in the template to "newMedical School_fromDate" and the code worked as before.  This is supported by looking at where the ref
name is used in the latest Vue source code (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js), apparently in just the below function.  Because "key" in `refs[key]` is specified with bracket notation, rather than dot notation, the
ref name does *not* have to be a valid Javascript identifier (which don't allow for spaces).

```
  function registerRef (vnode, isRemoval) {
    var key = vnode.data.ref;
    if (!isDef(key)) { return }

    var vm = vnode.context;
    var ref = vnode.componentInstance || vnode.elm;
    var refs = vm.$refs;
    if (isRemoval) {
      if (Array.isArray(refs[key])) {
        remove(refs[key], ref);
      } else if (refs[key] === ref) {
        refs[key] = undefined;
      }
    } else {
      if (vnode.data.refInFor) {
        if (!Array.isArray(refs[key])) {
          refs[key] = [ref];
        } else if (refs[key].indexOf(ref) < 0) {
          // $flow-disable-line
          refs[key].push(ref);
        }
      } else {
        refs[key] = ref;
      }
    }
  }
```